# python: Finding a substring within a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program which counts how many times a substring appears within a string.

```
word = "wejmfoiwstreetstreetskkjoih"
streets = "streets"
count = 0

if streets in word:
    count += 1

print(count)
```

as you can see "streets" appears twice but the last s of streets is also the beginning of streets. I can't think of a way to loop this.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe start here, https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Just so you know, a proper substr function typically only searches for one occurrence of the sub-string, and usually returns the index of it's position in the string. In your example, you are only searching for one occurrence as well, if streets in word well only increment count once, no matter how many times the sub string 'streets' shows up in your string. There are already some good answers here, I just wanted to provide some insight into why your function wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Can be done using a regex

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'streetstreets'
>>> len(re.findall('(?=streets)', text))
2
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> (?=...)
>
> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the
>   string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac
>   (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

Comment: That works, but this answer would be better if the regex was explained somewhat. In particular, what does the `?=` do, as it doesn't work with that omitted.

Comment: @EricWilson agreed, added the part from the docs where it's explained

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
>>> word = "wejmfoiwstreetstreetskkjoih"
>>> streets = "streets"
>>> sum(word[start:].startswith(streets) for start in range(len(word)))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic (though not as elegant) way would be a loop like this:

```
def count_substrings(stack, needle):
    idx = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        idx = stack.find(needle, idx) + 1 # next time look after this idx
        if idx <= 0:
            break
        count += 1
    return count
```

My measurement shows that it's ~8.5 times faster than the solution with `startswith` for every substring.